# mysql operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

My current query is this:

```
DELETE FROM a WHERE id=1
```

When I try to run it, I get the 1241 error code that the operand should contain 1 column(s).  I have also tried:

```
DELETE FROM a
WHERE id = (SELECT id
FROM (SELECT * FROM a WHERE a=1) AS a2)
```

Which also returns the same error when I run it.  This seems strange to be because I'm fairly certain I'm selecting only 1 column, and the output is only one column when I just run the inner select query.

But when I try:

```
DELETE FROM b WHERE id=1
```

The correct queries are deleted without issue.  Table `a` has `id` as its primary key, while table `b` has `id` as a foreign key.

Can anyone shed any light into this?

Comment: I suspect you have a broken delete trigger on `a`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i think that you are right, thanks a lot for the help